# Sending a "nmcli d wifi list" command using shell_exec() on php but not able to get full reply?

Tags: php, shell

I tried running the command

```
$results = shell_exec("nmcli device wifi list");


echo "<pre>".$results."</pre>";
```

It only list out 1 wifi connection around. When type on command line the same command, it list about 4-5 wifi connections available. Anyone has any idea how I can list all the wifi connect in the surrounding?

Comment: Plain PHP usage, or running below the webserver? You know, nmcli is subject to all sorts of dbus shenanigans, not to speak of resolving/detection delays. iwconfig is typically more authentic.

Comment: I used nmcli because it is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but its not exactly what I wanted but it does the output that I wanted.

```
$list = shell_exec('nmcli -e yes device wifi list');
echo "<pre>".$list."</pre";
```

I realised that when nmcli output results with escape between each connection, PHP can only read the first one.

so -e yes can escape it into a chank and output the entire results.

I am not sure if this explain correctly. Also the shell_exec still not able to choose how long to wait for all the data to be out. So it doesn't exactly does what I asked but it still gives me the results I want.

If anyone has a better answer kind please share, I like to learn as well.